# Asp.Net - Fire Click event before modal popup

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

my imagebutton doesn't fire click event. Just modal popup opening.

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" **data-target="#imgModal"**>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgGallery" 
                           ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Path") %>' 
                     CssClass="thumbnail img-responsive" runat="server" **OnClick="imgGallery_Click"** ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </a>
```

and

```
protected void imgGallery_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

    {
        ImageButton b = sender as ImageButton;
        string Id = b.Attributes["ImageUrl"];
    }
```

Simply, my question is how can I trigger OnClick event before modal popup opening ? And of course after click event I need to open my modal also.

Comment: Any one help me ?

Comment: Why do you need to go to the server? Maybe we can change the approach.

Comment: how ? Can you give me some idea ? @kblok

Comment: What do you need to do on the server side?

Comment: Im not sure understand you.

Comment: Why do you need the OnClick in the image?